# Loading local .HTML-file with WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I've read many descriptions on how to make this work, but it doesn't in my emulator, which is really frustrating. Should be piece of cake!

I made a supersimple html-file:

```
 <html>

    <head>
<h1> Hello </h1>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>


</html>
```

And then I use this java code to implement it:

```
    package com.path.path;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;



public class hello extends Activity {

WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hello);



     String url =  "file:///assets/hello.html";
    webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.char_view);
    webView.loadUrl(url);


}
```

}

When I load this page in the emulator it says the page is not available. What am I missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change `file:///assets/hello.html` to `file:///android_asset/hello.html`. This assumes that your HTML file is located at `assets/hello.html` in your project.

Also, move your `<h1>` element into the `<body>`, so that it will actually work.

Comment: It was as easy as that, been stuck with this silly issue all day! Thank you CommonsWare, I would vote up your Answer if I had those 15 rep..

Comment: David you don't have to up vote, this should be selected as the answer